# Whole string not getting read while reading the file using Config::IniFiles

Tags: perl

I am unable to print the whole lines as i try and parse the ini file using Config:Ini operation, its the last part where I believed that the array will have the whole line and not only the key, I am surely missing something here

Input

```
[DomainCredentials]

broker=SERVER
domain=CUSTOMER1

[ProviderCredentials]

Class=A
Routine=B
```

Code

```
#!/sbin/perl -w

use lib "/usr/lib/perl5/site_perl";
use lib "/usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl";

use strict;
use warnings;
use Config::IniFiles;
my $sPPFile="/tmp/config.txt";
my $sysSec="DomainCredentials";
my $cfg = Config::IniFiles->new(-file=> $sPPFile) || die "Could open file $sPPFile\n";
if ($@){
        print "Error";
        exit 1;
}
my @params_provider = $cfg->Parameters("ProviderCredentials");
foreach (@params_provider){
print $_."\n";
}
```

Output

```
Class
Routine
```

Expected Output

```
Class=A
Routine=B
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [tied hash option of Config::IniFiles](http://search.cpan.org/~shlomif/Config-IniFiles-2.82/lib/Config/IniFiles.pm#USAGE_--_Tied_Hash) to get the config.txt parameter/value pairs:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Config::IniFiles;

my %ini;
my $sPPFile = "/tmp/config.txt";
tie %ini, 'Config::IniFiles', ( -file => $sPPFile );

print "$_=$ini{ProviderCredentials}{$_}\n"
  for keys %{ $ini{ProviderCredentials} };
```

Output on your dataset:

```
Class=A
Routine=B
```

You can change the value of a parameter, and then update the config file by doing this:

```
$ini{ProviderCredentials}{Class} = 'C';
tied(%ini)->RewriteConfig();
```

The last command actually writes out the entire config held in the tied hash.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I did this `my %ini;
tie %ini, 'Config::IniFiles', ( -file => $sPPFile );
foreach (%{$ini{ProviderCredentials}}){
#       print "Key : ".$_."\t Value : ".$cfg->val("ProviderCredentials",$_)."\n";
        print $_."\n";
}
`output I got is `Class \n A \n Routine \b B`  All in 4 differebt lines

Comment: @learner - you've passed a hash to `foreach`: `foreach (%{$ini{ProviderCredentials}}){` and you're printing the returned list of hash elements.  Try `foreach (keys %{$ini{ProviderCredentials}}){` and `print "$_=$ini{ProviderCredentials}{$_}\n"` in side the loop.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like Parameters only returns keys.

You then have to use `val` to get the values.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/sbin/perl -w

use lib "/usr/lib/perl5/site_perl";
use lib "/usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl";

use strict;
use warnings;
use Config::IniFiles;
my $sPPFile="/tmp/config.txt";
my $sysSec="DomainCredentials";
my $cfg = Config::IniFiles->new(-file=> $sPPFile) || die "Could open file $sPPFile\n";
if ($@){
        print "Error";
        exit 1;
}
my @param_arr = ('broker','domain');
my %param_hash;

foreach my $p (@param_arr){
        if (defined $cfg->val("$sysSec",$p)){
                $param_hash{$p} = $cfg->val("$sysSec",$p);
        }
        else{
                die "Could not get parameter $p\n";
        }
}
#print $param_hash{broker};
#print $param_hash{domain};

my @params_provider = $cfg->Parameters("ProviderCredentials");
if (defined $cfg->Parameters("ProviderCredentials")){
        my @params_provider = $cfg->Parameters("ProviderCredentials");
}else{
        die "Could not get parameter ProviderCredentials\n";
}

foreach (@params_provider){
        print "Key : ".$_."\t Value : ".$cfg->val("ProviderCredentials",$_)."\n";
}
```